# Key-value map of each value of an enum in Java

Tags: java, performance

#### Task

In a Java back-end project, I have some (100+) external enums that I can't edit and I need to output them to our front-end. I wanted to output them in a JSON-object like manner. Each enum has different properties name.

e.g. for the following enum

```java
public enum Colors {
  RED(1, "RED", "ff0000", Boolean.TRUE),
  GREEN(2, "GREEN", "00ff00", Boolean.FALSE),
  BLUE(3, "BLUE", "0000ff", Boolean.TRUE);

  private int code;
  private String label;
  private String hexCode;
  private boolean isAwesome;

  // ... getters and other methods
}
```

i want to output

```
[
  {
    label: "RED"
    hexCode: "ff0000"
    isAwesome: true
  },
  {
    label: "GREEN"
    hexCode: "00ff00"
    isAwesome: false
  },
  ...
]
```

#### My attempt

I am new to Java, this is the first time I used reflection and I didn't really study anything before going into this. Probably there are some major problems with this code (like performance or some other weird stuff that I don't know), but it compiles and does the job. I don't know if this is safe, so I ask if there are some better ways to do this.

```java
private <T> List<HashMap<String, Object>> enumInserter(Class<T> clazz, List<String> properties) {
    return valuesToMap(clazz.getEnumConstants(), parserFactory(clazz, properties));
}

/**
* 
* @param <T>    type of the enum class
* @param values enumConstants of the enum
* @param parser a function that take a single enumValue of type <T> and returns
*               an property-value map
* @return the array of the property-value maps of each value
*/
private <T> List<HashMap<String, Object>> valuesToMap(T[] values, Function<T, HashMap<String, Object>> parser) {
  List<HashMap<String, Object>> enumValues = new ArrayList<>();
  for (T enumValue : values) {
    HashMap<String, Object> processedValue = parser.apply(enumValue);
    enumValues.add(processedValue);
  }
  return enumValues;
}

/**
* 
* @param <T>        the type of the enum class
* @param clazz      the enum class
* @param properties the properties to be added in the map
* @return a parser function that take a single enumValue of type <T> as input and
*         returns a property-value map of the given enumValue
*/
private <T> Function<T, HashMap<String, Object>> parserFactory(Class<T> clazz, List<String> properties) {
  return ((T enumValue) -> {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    properties.stream().forEach(propertyName -> {
      String methodName = getterFromProperty(propertyName);
      try {
        Method method = clazz.getMethod(methodName);
        Object methodResult = method.invoke(enumValue);
        map.put(propertyName, methodResult);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // ... error logging
      }
    });

    return map;
  });
}

/**
* Return the "standard" property getter of a property. e.g. "example" will
* return "getExample"
* 
* @param property
* @return property getter method name
*/
private String getterFromProperty(String property) {
  return "get" + property.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + property.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Why did you try to use reflection, does the `enum` class in question not have getters to retrieve your values?

Comment: Yes, each enum class have getters, but they have different names, so I didn't know how to get differently named properties in a generic way.
For example I can do `color.getHexCode()` where `color` is a enum value of `Colors` but for other enums i need other getters

Comment: You can just loop through your `enums` and use the getters to get each value you want. Get an array of all values like so: `Colors.values()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to this is either through use of annotation `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` or through usage of a custom tailored serializer.

Lets say that you are referencing the enum from class  A

```
class A {

   @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
   private Colors color;

}
```

this will make the color to be serialized the way you want.

Alternative aproach would to register a custom serializer for your Enum this you can do the following way:

```
public class ColorSerializer extends StdSerializer {

    public ColorSerializer() {
        super(Color.class);
    }

    public ColorSerializer(Class t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public void serialize(Color color, JsonGenerator generator,
      SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeFieldName("code");
        generator.writeString(color.getCode());
        generator.writeFieldName("hexCode");
        generator.writeString(color.getHexcode());
        generator.writeFieldName("isAwsome");
        generator.writeNumber(color.isAwsome());
        generator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

**Since your enums are external you can always place them in wrappers which are internal to your project and this way control their serialization process.**

If you want to serialize them using the same strategy you can place your reflection code in the serializer. This way you will get a single generic serializer, instead of writing for each enum.

This is how you can register the custom serializer:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Color.class, new ColorSerializer ());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: I know about the annotation but I can't edit the enum class and I din't want to wrap all of them. If I use the customSerializer approach, if I have some object that uses my Color enum, will the enum be parsed as object or like now, as a simple string? Because I want that this JSON-like serialization is used only for a specific service, I am fine with the simple string in all the other cases

Comment: If you use a custom serializer for Color and register it globaly. Every time you reference Color it will be serialized the way you want. And as I have pointed bellow if you have to serialize all enums using the same strategy you can write 1 single serializer implementing it. It can be based on reflecton as you have started doing.

Comment: @beegotsy if you are importing other objects than the enums and they reference Color registering custom serializer will make them also utilize it, as long as it is global.

Comment: Okay, I will try to register a non global serializer, because I need the previous behaviour on all the other services that use the enums

Comment: This mean you need to create objectmapper dedicated to your services.